Is it possible to use standard Ikea hinge for an inset door?
The title really says it all. I know these hinges are for overlay doors, but has anybody made them work with inset doors?

Generally, overlay doors and inset doors require different hinges to work well. I'd suggest getting hinges intended for the purpose rather than using Ikea leftovers -- or look at what Ikea offers that actually fits your intended use, if you must buy Ikea.

some big box stores have the various types of hinges displayed on miniature doors that you can open ... also, this may help https://duckduckgo.com/?q=european+hinges&iax=images&ia=images

Not ikea, but these: https://www.rockler.com/blum-soft-close-110-blumotion-clip-top-inset-hinges-for-frameless-cabinets?country=US&promo=shopping&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=&utm_content=pla_with_promotion&utm_campaign=PL&utm_campaign=18291976996&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=18291976996%7C%7C&utm_content=&gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiA0MG5BhD1ARIsAEcZtwTOO1WHPNMXBkPH1GerulQfIiCchJ49OUBDJsxdPtCqWUfITwSUsmMaAnI2EALw_wcB
